# Added features to "Virtual pet" game but I can't find my error

Tags: javascript, function, game-loop

I just added a sleep and hunger feature to my virtual pet and now the script wont work, i'm not sure what I did wrong since everything is looking good. I will show you the original script (which works) and my modded one.

I'm not quite sure what I have missed, I have spent a considerable amount of time looking through to find my mistake, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Original:

```html
<!-- Developed @ the University of Advancing Technology for use in UAT courses. -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Virtual Pet</title>
<script>
// Virtual Pet Stats and starting values
// TODO: Change the name of your Virtual Pet on the line below.
var petName = "Virtual Pet";
var currentHealth = 60;
var maxHealth = 100;
var petStatus = "healthy";
// TODO: Add more Virtual Pet stats that will be modified by your functions



// Increases the current health of the Virtual Pet until it is maxed out.
function exercise()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth + 5;
 if(currentHealth  > maxHealth)
 {
  currentHealth = maxHealth;
 }
 
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

// TODO: Write new functions that will process and modify the new stats you have created. (The majority of your new code should go here.)









// Modifies any stats that automatically change every few seconds. 
//    (For example, health decreases every few seconds so the play needs to occationally exercise their Virtual Pet)
function changesOverTime()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth - 4;
 // TODO: Add in other changes to the Virtual Pet stats that occur on a regular basis.
 
}


// Checks the pet's health and modifies the status accordingly
function checkHealth()
{
 if(currentHealth <= 0 )
 {
  petStatus = "Dead";
        currentHealth = 0;
 }
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
}


// Displays a Title to the screen for your Virtual Pet game
function displayTitle()
{
 // TODO (Optional): Create your own title
 
}


// Displays the current pet stats to the screen.
function displayPetStats()
{
 document.write("<h2>" + petName + " Status: " + petStatus + "</h2>");
 document.write("<p>Health = " + currentHealth + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Health = " + maxHealth + "</p>");
 // TODO: Add the display of new Virtual Pet stats here
 
 
 document.close();
}


// Displays the buttons to the screen enabling the user to interact with their virtual pet.
function displayUserOptions()
{
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
  document.write("<button onclick='exercise()'>Exercise</button>");
  
  // TODO: Create buttons for other actions
  
 }
}


// Calls all the functions that display information to the screen.
function updateDisplay()
{
 displayTitle();
 displayUserOptions();
 displayPetStats();

}


// This function executes the game and manages the passing of time.
function gameLoop(timestamp)
{
 if(timestamp > last_iteration + time_interval)
 {
  last_iteration = timestamp;
  
  changesOverTime();
  checkHealth();
  
  // TODO: Check other Virtual Pet stats and update the petStatus accordingly
        
        
        
        
        // After all stats updates are done, update/recreate the display
        updateDisplay();
 }
 
 
 
 // Life continues unless the Virtual Pet is dead (health <= 0)
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
        // Executes the gameLoop function once again.
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
 }
}

// Other global variables that control the timing of the game.
var time_interval = 5000;
var last_iteration = 0;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Virtual Pet!</h1>
<!-- Initiate the gameLoop for the first time.-->
<button onclick='gameLoop()'>Bring my Virtual Pet to Life!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My modded script:

```html
<!-- Developed @ the University of Advancing Technology for use in UAT courses. -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Virtual Pet</title>
<script>
// Virtual Pet Stats and starting values
// TODO: Change the name of your Virtual Pet on the line below.
var petName = "Virtual Pet";
var currentHealth = 60;
var maxHealth = 100;
var petStatus = "healthy";
var tiredness = 60;
var maxTiredness = 100;
var hunger = 60;
var maxHunger = 100;
// TODO: Add more Virtual Pet stats that will be modified by your functions



// Increases the current health of the Virtual Pet until it is maxed out.
function exercise()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth + 5;
 if(currentHealth  > maxHealth)
 {
  currentHealth = maxHealth;
 }
 
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

function sleep(){
 var sleepamount = prompt("How many minutes would you like to sleep?");
 tiredness + sleepamount = tiredness;
 if tiredness >= 100 {
 tiredness = 100;
 }
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}
function checkHunger(){
 var feed = prompt("How many snacks do you want to eat?");
 hunger + feed = hunger;
 if hunger >= 100 {
 hunger = 100;
}
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

// TODO: Write new functions that will process and modify the new stats you have created. (The majority of your new code should go here.)









// Modifies any stats that automatically change every few seconds. 
//    (For example, health decreases every few seconds so the play needs to occationally exercise their Virtual Pet)
function changesOverTime()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth - 4;
 tiredness = tiredness - 4;
 hunger = hunger - 4;
 // TODO: Add in other changes to the Virtual Pet stats that occur on a regular basis.
 
}


// Checks the pet's health and modifies the status accordingly
function checkHealth()
{
 if(currentHealth <= 0 )
 {
  petStatus = "Dead";
        currentHealth = 0;
 }
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
}
function checkStarved()
{
 if(hunger <= 0 ){
  petStatus = "Dead";
        hunger = 0;
 } else if hunger >= 30 && hunger <= 75 {
  petStatus = "Hungry";
 
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
 }
}


// Displays a Title to the screen for your Virtual Pet game
function displayTitle()
{
 // TODO (Optional): Create your own title
 
}


// Displays the current pet stats to the screen.
function displayPetStats()
{
 document.write("<h2>" + petName + " Status: " + petStatus + "</h2>");
 document.write("<p>Health = " + currentHealth + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Health = " + maxHealth + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Hunger = " + hunger + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Hunger = " + maxHunger + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Tiredness = " + tiredness + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Tiredness = " + maxTiredness + "</p>");
 // TODO: Add the display of new Virtual Pet stats here
 
 
 document.close();
}


// Displays the buttons to the screen enabling the user to interact with their virtual pet.
function displayUserOptions()
{
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
  document.write("<button onclick='exercise()'>Exercise</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='sleep()'>Sleep</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='checkHunger()'>Feed</button>");
  
  // TODO: Create buttons for other actions
  
 }
}


// Calls all the functions that display information to the screen.
function updateDisplay()
{
 displayTitle();
 displayUserOptions();
 displayPetStats();

}


// This function executes the game and manages the passing of time.
function gameLoop(timestamp)
{
 if(timestamp > last_iteration + time_interval)
 {
  last_iteration = timestamp;
  
  changesOverTime();
  checkHealth();
  checkStarved()
  
  // TODO: Check other Virtual Pet stats and update the petStatus accordingly
        
        
        
        
        // After all stats updates are done, update/recreate the display
        updateDisplay();
 }
 
 
 
 // Life continues unless the Virtual Pet is dead (health <= 0)
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
        // Executes the gameLoop function once again.
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
 }
}

// Other global variables that control the timing of the game.
var time_interval = 5000;
var last_iteration = 0;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Virtual Pet!</h1>
<!-- Initiate the gameLoop for the first time.-->
<button onclick='gameLoop()'>Bring my Virtual Pet to Life!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this `hunger + feed = hunger;` in invalid. You surely mean `hunger += feed;`

Comment: Good catch I did change hunger + feed = hunger to feed += hunger

Comment: I also changed tiredness + sleepamount = tiredness to sleepamount += tiredness but it still wont run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're have a two errors multiple times.

Assigning variables the statement needs to be on the left-side of the = sign, tiredness + hunger = hunger needs to be hunger = tiredness + hunger

if statements are missing (), if hunger > 0 { } needs to be if (hunger > 0) { }

Here is an updated script.

```html
<!-- Developed @ the University of Advancing Technology for use in UAT courses. -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Virtual Pet</title>
<script>
// Virtual Pet Stats and starting values
// TODO: Change the name of your Virtual Pet on the line below.
var petName = "Virtual Pet";
var currentHealth = 60;
var maxHealth = 100;
var petStatus = "healthy";
var tiredness = 60;
var maxTiredness = 100;
var hunger = 60;
var maxHunger = 100;
// TODO: Add more Virtual Pet stats that will be modified by your functions



// Increases the current health of the Virtual Pet until it is maxed out.
function exercise()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth + 5;
 if(currentHealth  > maxHealth)
 {
  currentHealth = maxHealth;
 }
 
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

function sleep(){
 var sleepamount = prompt("How many minutes would you like to sleep?");
 tiredness = sleepamount + tiredness;
 if (tiredness >= 100) {
 tiredness = 100;
 }
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}
function checkHunger(){
 var feed = prompt("How many snacks do you want to eat?");
 hunger = feed + hunger;
 if (hunger >= 100) {
 hunger = 100;
}
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

// TODO: Write new functions that will process and modify the new stats you have created. (The majority of your new code should go here.)









// Modifies any stats that automatically change every few seconds. 
//    (For example, health decreases every few seconds so the play needs to occationally exercise their Virtual Pet)
function changesOverTime()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth - 4;
 tiredness = tiredness - 4;
 hunger = hunger - 4;
 // TODO: Add in other changes to the Virtual Pet stats that occur on a regular basis.
 
}


// Checks the pet's health and modifies the status accordingly
function checkHealth()
{
 if(currentHealth <= 0 )
 {
  petStatus = "Dead";
        currentHealth = 0;
 }
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
}
function checkStarved()
{
 if(hunger <= 0 ){
  petStatus = "Dead";
        hunger = 0;
 } else if (hunger >= 30 && hunger <= 75) {
  petStatus = "Hungry";
 
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
 }
}


// Displays a Title to the screen for your Virtual Pet game
function displayTitle()
{
 // TODO (Optional): Create your own title
 
}


// Displays the current pet stats to the screen.
function displayPetStats()
{
 document.write("<h2>" + petName + " Status: " + petStatus + "</h2>");
 document.write("<p>Health = " + currentHealth + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Health = " + maxHealth + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Hunger = " + hunger + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Hunger = " + maxHunger + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Tiredness = " + tiredness + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Tiredness = " + maxTiredness + "</p>");
 // TODO: Add the display of new Virtual Pet stats here
 
 
 document.close();
}


// Displays the buttons to the screen enabling the user to interact with their virtual pet.
function displayUserOptions()
{
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
  document.write("<button onclick='exercise()'>Exercise</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='sleep()'>Sleep</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='checkHunger()'>Feed</button>");
  
  // TODO: Create buttons for other actions
  
 }
}


// Calls all the functions that display information to the screen.
function updateDisplay()
{
 displayTitle();
 displayUserOptions();
 displayPetStats();

}


// This function executes the game and manages the passing of time.
function gameLoop(timestamp)
{
 if(timestamp > last_iteration + time_interval)
 {
  last_iteration = timestamp;
  
  changesOverTime();
  checkHealth();
  checkStarved()
  
  // TODO: Check other Virtual Pet stats and update the petStatus accordingly
        
        
        
        
        // After all stats updates are done, update/recreate the display
        updateDisplay();
 }
 
 
 
 // Life continues unless the Virtual Pet is dead (health <= 0)
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
        // Executes the gameLoop function once again.
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
 }
}

// Other global variables that control the timing of the game.
var time_interval = 5000;
var last_iteration = 0;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Virtual Pet!</h1>
<!-- Initiate the gameLoop for the first time.-->
<button onclick='gameLoop()'>Bring my Virtual Pet to Life!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am happy to have learned that the variable needs to be on the left side, this is what was breaking my code! Also thanks for the other answer to my mistake as well.

Answer (score 1):

There were two things wrong in the code:

- The left-hand-side of `=` must be a variable. You are using something `tiredness + sleepamount = tiredness` this is some places. Change it to `tiredness = tiredness + sleepamount`
- The conditions of `if` should be in `()` but you are using like this `hunger >= 100`

```html
<!-- Developed @ the University of Advancing Technology for use in UAT courses. -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Virtual Pet</title>
<script>
// Virtual Pet Stats and starting values
// TODO: Change the name of your Virtual Pet on the line below.
var petName = "Virtual Pet";
var currentHealth = 60;
var maxHealth = 100;
var petStatus = "healthy";
var tiredness = 60;
var maxTiredness = 100;
var hunger = 60;
var maxHunger = 100;
// TODO: Add more Virtual Pet stats that will be modified by your functions
// Increases the current health of the Virtual Pet until it is maxed out.
function exercise()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth + 5;
 if(currentHealth  > maxHealth)
 {
  currentHealth = maxHealth;
 }    
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

function sleep(){
 var sleepamount = prompt("How many minutes would you like to sleep?");
 tiredness = tiredness + sleepamount;
 if (tiredness >= 100) {
    tiredness = 100;
 }
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}
function checkHunger(){
 var feed = prompt("How many snacks do you want to eat?");
 hunger = hunger + feed;
 if (hunger >= 100) {
 hunger = 100;
}
    // Update the display after an action has occurred.
 updateDisplay();
}

// TODO: Write new functions that will process and modify the new stats you have created. (The majority of your new code should go here.)

// Modifies any stats that automatically change every few seconds. 
//    (For example, health decreases every few seconds so the play needs to occationally exercise their Virtual Pet)
function changesOverTime()
{
 currentHealth = currentHealth - 4;
 tiredness = tiredness - 4;
 hunger = hunger - 4;
 // TODO: Add in other changes to the Virtual Pet stats that occur on a regular basis.   
}
// Checks the pet's health and modifies the status accordingly
function checkHealth()
{
 if(currentHealth <= 0 )
 {
  petStatus = "Dead";
        currentHealth = 0;
 }     
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
}
function checkStarved()
{
 if(hunger <= 0 ){
  petStatus = "Dead";
        hunger = 0;
 } else if (hunger >= 30 && hunger <= 75) {
  petStatus = "Hungry";
 
 
 //TODO (Optional): Add other health status checks (For example, sick if health < 15)
 }
}
// Displays a Title to the screen for your Virtual Pet game
function displayTitle()
{
 // TODO (Optional): Create your own title
 
}
// Displays the current pet stats to the screen.
function displayPetStats()
{
 document.write("<h2>" + petName + " Status: " + petStatus + "</h2>");
 document.write("<p>Health = " + currentHealth + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Health = " + maxHealth + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Hunger = " + hunger + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Hunger = " + maxHunger + "</p>");
 document.write("<p>Tiredness = " + tiredness + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Max Tiredness = " + maxTiredness + "</p>");
 // TODO: Add the display of new Virtual Pet stats here     
 document.close();
}
// Displays the buttons to the screen enabling the user to interact with their virtual pet.
function displayUserOptions()
{
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
  document.write("<button onclick='exercise()'>Exercise</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='sleep()'>Sleep</button>");
  document.write("<button onclick='checkHunger()'>Feed</button>");
  
  // TODO: Create buttons for other actions
  
 }
}
// Calls all the functions that display information to the screen.
function updateDisplay()
{
 displayTitle();
 displayUserOptions();
 displayPetStats();

}
// This function executes the game and manages the passing of time.
function gameLoop(timestamp)
{
 if(timestamp > last_iteration + time_interval)
 {
  last_iteration = timestamp;
  
  changesOverTime();
  checkHealth();
  checkStarved()  
  // TODO: Check other Virtual Pet stats and update the petStatus accordingly                                    
        // After all stats updates are done, update/recreate the display
        updateDisplay();
 }
 // Life continues unless the Virtual Pet is dead (health <= 0)
 if(petStatus != "Dead")
 {
        // Executes the gameLoop function once again.
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
 }
}
// Other global variables that control the timing of the game.
var time_interval = 5000;
var last_iteration = 0;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Virtual Pet!</h1>
<!-- Initiate the gameLoop for the first time.-->
<button onclick='gameLoop()'>Bring my Virtual Pet to Life!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the important lesson on putting variable to the left of the = sign and when to use ()!